# Change user DB connection at runtime in Keycloak user storage SPI

Tags: keycloak

We have a single Keycloak realm configured to be used from a different server for authentication. I am implementing Keycloak user storage API to look up from user database. Each server can have a different user database.

I can determine the database to connect based on request details but not sure how can I get the same in user storage API.

**Update:**

I can also do with identifying client ID.

Another option can be to let the SPI implementation invoke a REST API to validate credentials to simplify keycloak configuration. However this would also need some identifier to determine database.

Please advise.

Comment: So you want that at run-time redirect  the request to the connect to the correct DB?

Comment: Yes. I want to determine DB connection based on the requesting server.

Comment: That is not possible, if you want I can provided an answer why if you interested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keycloak does not provide request URL to user storage SPI implementation. It does provide realm and client IDs. If required, realm or client values can be used to determine required action.